# gem cleanup removes needed versions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

When I run `gem cleanup -d` it lists several gem versions that are dependencies. The gems that depend on them are listed in the Gemfile in a jekyll install I have via my github repo, which I suspect is why gem doesn't see the dependencies.

Is there a way to tell gem to look at the jekyll install's Gemfile for dependencies?

Or is it actually another problem?

TIA.

Comment: I think you need bundler for that.

Comment: Could you be more specific?